# How to access values from a dictionary inside a list based on another key-value pair?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the list below,

```
graph = [{'Node':'A', 'children':['T','Z','S'], 'gWt':[118,75,140], 'h':366},
         {'Node':'Z', 'children':['O','A'], 'gWt':[71,75], 'h':374},
         {'Node':'T', 'children':['A'], 'gWt':[118], 'h':329},
         {'Node':'S', 'children':['A','O','R','F'], 'gWt':[140,151,80,99], 'h':253}]
```

For a given node value, how would i get all of its 'children'?
For example,

```
graph.index('Node'=='S')['children'] -> ['A','O','R','F']
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have the enclosing list? It could be a lot more efficient if `"Node"` is unique and could be set as the key to a dictionary. Otherwise, you're forced to iterate the list

Comment: @roganjosh Not necessary but how will you group all these values otherwise?

Comment: Where are you having problems?  This appears to be straightforward access of Python data structures.

Comment: I edited my comment

Comment: Hi @motox, I explained how you can store the graph more efficiently to perform the queries you want and how to convert it to that data structure in case you don't have control of the input. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Comments on using `index()` or `next()`:

Creating a list of the node names and then finding the index of a node by using the `index()` is the way to go but notice that this can lead to huge performance downgrade as well as logical errors.

- Performance issues: Finding in a list using `list.index(target)` is **O(n)**, meaning that it iterates over every element in the list until it finds the **first** element that matches the target which is not ideal.
- Logic errors: If you were to have a malformed graph, a list containing the same node name twice or more, e.g.: `graph = [{"node": "A", ...props1}, {"node": "A", ... props2}]`, you'll only encounter the first node because of the nature of the `index()` function. If you want to find every node `"A"` then you'll need to run `index()` over all the list until you are sure you've found all nodes `"A"` and then think on a merge strategy for the node properties.

### Solution (recommendation):

Store the graph's nodes by using a dictionary. Dictionaries have constant time lookups (**O(1)**) since they are [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The representation you are looking to achieve is:

```py
graph = {
    "A": {'children':['T','Z','S'], 'gWt':[118,75,140], 'h':366},
    "B": {'children':['O','A'], 'gWt':[71,75], 'h':374},
    ...
}
```

Which will also make the traversal of your graph super easy. This way, whenever you are looking for the node `"X"` you only have to `graph["X"]` to obtain it, and `graph["X"]["children"]` to obtain its children.

#### How to transform the given input into the optimum data structure?

If you cannot construct the data structure mentioned above, then you'll definitively want to transform it into the optimum one if you are planning to query the graph's nodes properties constantly. You can achieve that with:

```py
def transform_graph(graph):
    new_graph = {}
    for node in graph:
        node_name = node['Node']
        new_graph[node_name] = new_graph.get(
            node_name,
            {'children': set(), 'gWt': set(), 'h': 0}
        )
        new_graph[node_name]["children"] |= set(node['children'])
        new_graph[node_name]["gWt"] |= set(node["gWt"])
        new_graph[node_name]["h"] = node["h"]
    return new_graph
```

The output of calling the function `transform_graph(old_graph)` is

```py
old_graph = [
    {'Node':'A', 'children':['T','Z','S'], 'gWt':[118,75,140], 'h':366},
    {'Node':'Z', 'children':['O','A'], 'gWt':[71,75], 'h':374},
    {'Node':'T', 'children':['A'], 'gWt':[118], 'h':329},
    {'Node':'S', 'children':['A','O','R','F'], 'gWt':[140,151,80,99], 'h':253}
]
new_graph = transform_graph(old_graph)
print(new_graph)

> {
    'A': {'children': {'S', 'T', 'Z'}, 'gWt': {75, 118, 140}, 'h': 366},
    'Z': {'children': {'A', 'O'}, 'gWt': {71, 75}, 'h': 374},
    'T': {'children': {'A'}, 'gWt': {118}, 'h': 329},
    'S': {'children': {'A', 'F', 'O', 'R'}, 'gWt': {80, 99, 140, 151}, 'h': 253}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is one and only one value equals to `'S'`, you could use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
graph = [{'Node':'A', 'children':['T','Z','S'], 'gWt':[118,75,140], 'h':366},
         {'Node':'Z', 'children':['O','A'], 'gWt':[71,75], 'h':374},
         {'Node':'T', 'children':['A'], 'gWt':[118], 'h':329},
         {'Node':'S', 'children':['A','O','R','F'], 'gWt':[140,151,80,99], 'h':253}]

result = next(e for e in graph if e['Node'] == 'S')['children']
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'O', 'R', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

I fell like your data in the best format it could be, but this does the job:

```
graph[[x['Node'] for x in graph].index('S')]['children']
```

will print

```
 ['A', 'O', 'R', 'F']
```